# SQLite: Fetching data from one table based on 2 differeet ID values into 2nd table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two tables named `List` and `Task`.

- List table is composed by two columns: `ListID` and `NAME`
- Task table is composed by: `TaskId`,`TaskListId`,`Name`,`Notes`,`Completed` and `Hidden`

There are 3 list ID which creates 3 tabs named `Personal`,`Business` and `History` using `TabManager`

What I need is if I delete a task from personal or business then it is hidden by setting Hidden=1. Then I want to show that in my History tab. How to achieve this.
How to write query for this in SQLite.? I need a query something like below

```
Select * from Task where (TaskListID=1 or 2 // this is the part giving me problem as TaskListId decides which task belongs to which tab like 1=personal,2=business ) AND hidden==1;
```

following is the method refreshTaskList() used to display data for current tab.

```
public void refreshTaskList() {

// get task list for current tab from database
Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
TaskListDB db = new TaskListDB(context);

//ArrayList<Task> tasks=new ArrayList<Task>();
if(Objects.equals(currentTabTag, "History"))
{

ArrayList<Task> tasks=db.getHistory(currentTabTag);
TaskListAdapter adapter = new TaskListAdapter(context, tasks);
taskListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}else
{
ArrayList<Task>tasks2=db.getTasks(currentTabTag);
TaskListAdapter adapter = new TaskListAdapter(context, tasks2);
taskListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Also following are the getTasks and getHistory methods used to pull tasks from database for current Tab.

```
public ArrayList<Task> getTasks(String listName) {
    String where =
                TASK_LIST_ID + "= ? AND " +
                        TASK_HIDDEN + "!='1'";
        long listID = getList(listName).getId();
        String[] whereArgs = {Long.toString(listID)};

        this.openReadableDB();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TASK_TABLE, null,
                where, whereArgs,
                null, null, null);
        ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            tasks.add(getTaskFromCursor(cursor));
        }
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
        this.closeDB();
        return tasks;
    }

public ArrayList<Task> getHistory(String listName)
{
    String where =
            TASK_LIST_ID + "= ? AND " +
                    TASK_HIDDEN + "=='1'";
    long listID = getList(listName).getId();
    String[] whereArgs = {Long.toString(listID)};


    this.openReadableDB();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TASK_TABLE, null,
            where, whereArgs,
            null, null, null);

    Log.v(TAG,"Value of cursor is-" +cursor);
    ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        tasks.add(getTaskFromCursor(cursor));
    }
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close();
    this.closeDB();

    return tasks;

 }
```

**What I think is that the TASK_LIST_ID acts as a foreign key which decides which task belongs to which tab in DB. So what I need is a such query where I can get the tasks from both tabs namely Personal and Business and put them in History if their Hidden value is set to 1 .**

Comment: `... where (TaskListID=1 or TaskListID=2) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 1 or 2 part is giving you hard time, then here you go:

`SELECT * FROM task WHERE TaskListID=1 OR TaskListID=2 AND HIDDEN=1`

Comment: how to use that in db.query() method..? means how to form where  and whereargs etc..

Comment: @saurabhsarpotdar Use `rawQuery()`

Comment: `WHERE (TaskListID=1 OR TaskListID=2) AND HIDDEN=1`

Comment: @Rotwang thank you so much...rawQuery() worked.. than you Vladimir and mihail also.